# SVN tree conflict on merge from files that were added

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a SVN branch [a] that I want to merge some updates from the trunk into. These changes included some added directories and files that did not originally exist in [a]. When I attempt the merge from the trunk into [a], there are tree conflicts on those added files/directories.

When I open the Edit Tree Conflicts dialogue (on one of the files, not directories), the error reads:

> The last merge operation tried to delete/move/rename the directory '[my added file]' but the file is missing locally (deleted or moved away?).

Source Left: [Repo Root]/trunk/myDirectory/[my added file]@1234

Source Right: [Repo Root]/branches/[a]/myDirectory/[my added file]@1234

The only option to remediate is to "Accept current working copy state (mark as resolved)", which isn't acceptable because I need those added folders/files.

To be clear, this is the series of events that took place:

1. Created branch [a]
2. Added [my added file] to Trunk (other files were modified)
3. Attempted to merge Trunk into [a] to get [my added file] (And other added directories, modified files)
4. Tree conflicts

Some of the added folders/files that need to be merged into [a] were merged into the trunk from another branch [b] (which was created sometime after the creation of [a])...there are tree conflicts on those as well that I don't understand, but [my added file] does not sit in those directories.

My question:

Since these files/directories never existed in [a], how is it possible that I could have tree conflicts on them, and what are some possible strategies that I can use to remediate them?